# Reuse sub table for multiple insert statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a situation where I need to insert data into two tables, where the inserted data is derived from the same long sub query. I know that CTEs can be helpful in similar situations since you can define a subquery once, and reuse it in multiple places in the subsequent statement. The problem is I don't have a single statement I want to use the subquery for, I have two, and my understanding is the CTEs only be used in a single statement.

So my question is how can I avoid repeating the

```
SELECT col1 
FROM table3 
WHERE col2 > 5 
  AND col2 < 10 
ORDER BY col2 DESC
```

part of the below?

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, othercol)
    SELECT col1, 'foo' 
    FROM
        (SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col2 > 5 AND col2 < 10 ORDER BY col2 DESC);
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, othercol)
    SELECT col1, 'bar' 
    FROM
        (SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col2 > 5 AND col2 < 10 ORDER BY col2 DESC);
```

Comment: I was all ready to use a `CTE` and a `UNION ALL` in the `SELECT` part of the `INSERT` ... until I saw you were inserting into two different tables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as a temp table first.

Use a better name than tmp :)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;

CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp
AS
SELECT col1 
FROM table3 
WHERE col2 > 5 AND col2 < 10 
ORDER BY col2 DESC;

INSERT INTO table1 (col1, othercol)
SELECT col1, 'foo' 
FROM tmp;

INSERT INTO table2 (col1, othercol)
SELECT col1, 'bar' 
FROM tmp;
```

Comment: Could the OP use a table variable instead of a temp table? (Or does PostgresSQL not support those?)

Comment: You can use record types, sure. But I think this is simpler. I'm sure the example is simplified, but I'd have to ask - if the grain is the same, why are there now three tables with the same data? There's something going on that we don't know about.

Answer (score 2):

See example.
CTEs can only be used in a single statement.
There RETURNING clause is helpful.
First INSERT operation in CTE returns all INSERTED rows.
Then insert them into second table.

```
with q1 as (
  INSERT INTO table2 (col1, othercol)
    SELECT col1, 'bar' 
    FROM
        (SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col2 > 5 AND col2 < 10 ORDER BY col2 DESC) SubQuery1
  returning *
)
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, othercol)
    SELECT col1, 'foo' 
    FROM q1
;
```

We can see on query plan, internal query runs 1 time.

```
QUERY PLAN
Insert on table1  (cost=22.99..23.07 rows=0 width=0)
  CTE q1
    ->  Insert on table2  (cost=22.94..22.99 rows=4 width=62)
          ->  Subquery Scan on subquery1  (cost=22.94..22.99 rows=4 width=62)
                ->  Sort  (cost=22.94..22.95 rows=4 width=8)
                      Sort Key: table3.col2 DESC
                      ->  Seq Scan on table3  (cost=0.00..22.90 rows=4 width=8)
                            Filter: ((col2 > 5) AND (col2 < 10))
  ->  CTE Scan on q1  (cost=0.00..0.08 rows=4 width=62)
```

Next query is the same as higher

```
with LongQuery as(
  SELECT col1 FROM table3 
  WHERE col2 > 5 AND col2 < 10 
  ORDER BY col2 DESC
)
,q1 as (
  INSERT INTO table2 (col1, othercol)
    SELECT col1, 'bar' 
    FROM LongQuery
  returning *
)
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, othercol)
    SELECT col1, 'foo' 
    FROM q1
;
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to do something like the below? It provides more flexibility because the subsequent INSERT is not dependent on the RETURNING of the previous one.

`WITH q1 AS ( SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col2 > 5 AND col2 < 10 ORDER BY col2 DESC), q2 AS ( INSERT INTO table1 (col1, othercol) SELECT col1, 'foo' FROM q1 )
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, othercol) SELECT col1, 'bar' FROM q1;`

Comment: In query example given in comment, an insert is made only into table2. CTE q2 is not used.

Comment: No, it works. Try running this: `CREATE TABLE table3 ( col1 INTEGER, col2 INTEGER );
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES ( 1, 6 ), ( 2, 7 ), ( 3, 8 ), ( 4, 2 ), ( 5, 10 ), ( 6, 11 );
CREATE TABLE table1 ( col1 INTEGER, othercol TEXT );
CREATE TABLE table2 ( col1 INTEGER, othercol TEXT );
WITH q1 AS ( SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col2 > 5 AND col2 < 10 ORDER BY col2 DESC),
q2 AS ( INSERT INTO table1 (col1, othercol) SELECT col1, 'foo' FROM q1 )
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, othercol)
    SELECT col1, 'bar' FROM q1;
SELECT * FROM table1;
SELECT * FROM table2;`

Comment: This is luck! This behavior is unexpected. Investigate possible change in order of execution when request is changed.